# How convert hand written notes into text notes in Android?

Tags: java, android, handwriting-recognition

I have to develop an Android app that includes French handwriting recognition. The problem is I have no idea where I've to start.

I have installed and run an application called `Thulika` but it seems that it's designed for emailing and the handwriting option doesn't work.

I've beeng trying to do this for more than a month. If anyone has better and easier solutions to handwriting recognition, feel free to suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your need is to convert handwriting from a screen (where a user uses a pen or a finger to write letters) then look at http://dev.myscript.com/ .

If you need to recognize handwriting from an image, then I'm afraid state of the art of such technology is still in "stone age". Hopefully in few years after heavy R&D we will see few handwritten SDK's around.